# Issue with tkinter __init__

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I was writing the following code but when run it threw an error about `main_window` and something about tkinter's `Widget.__init__()`:

```py
from tkinter import *
import random

class window_one:
    def init(self):
        Button(main_window,text="leave, do not return",command=self.quit).grid()
        number1 = Button(main_window="ένα/1",font="Gothic 26",bg="red",width=3,command=self.one)
        number2 = Button(main_window="δύο/2",font="Gothic 26",bg="red",width=3,command=self.two)
        number3 = Button(main_window="τρία/3",font="Gothic 26",bg="red",width=3,command=self.three)
        number4 = Button(main_window="τέσσερα/4",font="Gothic 26",bg="red",width=3,command=self.four)
        number5 = Button(main_window="πέντε/5",font="Gothic 26",bg="red",width=3,command=self.five)
        number6 = Button(main_window="έξι/6",font="Gothic 26",bg="red",width=3,command=self.six)
        number7 = Button(main_window="εφτά/7",font="Gothic 26",bg="red",width=3,command=self.seven)
        number8 = Button(main_window="οχτώ/8",font="Gothic 26",bg="red",width=3,command=self.eight)
        number9 = Button(main_window="εννιά/9",font="Gothic 26",bg="red",width=3,command=self.nine)

        canvas.create_window(45,150,window=number1)
        canvas.create_window(130,150,window=number2)
        canvas.create_window(215,150,window=number3)
        canvas.create_window(45,300,window=number4)
        canvas.create_window(130,300,window=number5)
        canvas.create_window(215,300,window=number6)
        canvas.create_window(45,450,window=number7)
        canvas.create_window(130,450,window=number8)
        canvas.create_window(215,450,window=number9)

    def quit(self):
        main_window.destroy()

    def one(self):
        print("You pressed one")

    def two(self):
        print("You pressed two")

    def three(self):
        print("You pressed three")

    def four(self):
        print("You pressed four")

    def five(self):
        print("You pressed five")

    def six(self):
        print("You pressed six")

    def seven(self):
        print("You pressed seven")

    def eight(self):
        print("You pressed eight")

    def nine(self):
        print("You pressed nine")

    def ten(self):
        print("You pressed ten")

main_window = Tk()
canvas = Canvas(main_window, width=600, height=300, bg='grey')
canvas.grid()

window_one()
```

This is what I get when running it:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\-----------\OneDrive - -------- -------\Documents\Greek calculator.py", line 79, in <module>
    window_one()
  File "C:\Users\-----------\OneDrive - ------\Documents\Greek calculator.py", line 6, in __init__
    number1 = Button(main_window="ένα/1",font="Gothic 26",bg="red",width=3,command=self.one)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2645, in __init__
    Widget.__init__(self, master, 'button', cnf, kw)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2567, in __init__
    self.tk.call(
_tkinter.TclError: unknown option "-main_window"
```

I checked tkinter's `__init__` file and found nothing wrong with it, it ran as normal.

Comment: `main_window="ένα/1"`. What's this?

Comment: please format your code properly, especially the first class

Comment: The code in your question does not match what is shown in the traceback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're getting the error because `main_window` isn't a valid option for creating a `Button`. It's pretty obvious you meant for `main_window` to be the first argument and the second to be `text="ένα/1"`, etc.

There are also some other errors in your code, most notably that the initializer method of the class should be named `__init__()` not `init()`. I've fixed that and a few other things in order to be able to run the code your question. I also streamlined parts of it a little bit and reformatted the code to be easier to read.

I strongly suggest you read and try to follow the [PEP 8 - Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) guidelines.

```
from tkinter import *


class window_one:
    def __init__(self):
        Button(main_window, text="leave, do not return", command=self.quit).grid()

        BTN_FNT = ('gothic', '26')
        BTN_WTH = 11
        BTN_BGR = 'red'
        number1 = Button(main_window, text="ένα/1", font=BTN_FNT, bg=BTN_BGR,
                         width=BTN_WTH, command=self.one)
        number2 = Button(main_window, text="δύο/2", font=BTN_FNT, bg=BTN_BGR,
                         width=BTN_WTH, command=self.two)
        number3 = Button(main_window, text="τρία/3", font=BTN_FNT, bg=BTN_BGR,
                         width=BTN_WTH, command=self.three)
        number4 = Button(main_window, text="τέσσερα/4", font=BTN_FNT, bg=BTN_BGR,
                         width=BTN_WTH, command=self.four)
        number5 = Button(main_window, text="πέντε/5", font=BTN_FNT, bg=BTN_BGR,
                         width=BTN_WTH, command=self.five)
        number6 = Button(main_window, text="έξι/6", font=BTN_FNT, bg=BTN_BGR,
                         width=BTN_WTH, command=self.six)
        number7 = Button(main_window, text="εφτά/7", font=BTN_FNT, bg=BTN_BGR,
                         width=BTN_WTH, command=self.seven)
        number8 = Button(main_window, text="οχτώ/8", font=BTN_FNT, bg=BTN_BGR,
                         width=BTN_WTH, command=self.eight)
        number9 = Button(main_window, text="εννιά/9", font=BTN_FNT, bg=BTN_BGR,
                         width=BTN_WTH, command=self.nine)

        btns = [[number1, number2, number3],
                [number4, number5, number6],
                [number7, number8, number9]]

        for i in range(3):
            y = i*75 + 70
            for j in range(3):
                x = j*200 + 125
                canvas.create_window(x, y, window=btns[i][j])

    def quit(self):
        main_window.destroy()

    def one(self):
        print("You pressed one")

    def two(self):
        print("You pressed two")

    def three(self):
        print("You pressed three")

    def four(self):
        print("You pressed four")

    def five(self):
        print("You pressed five")

    def six(self):
        print("You pressed six")

    def seven(self):
        print("You pressed seven")

    def eight(self):
        print("You pressed eight")

    def nine(self):
        print("You pressed nine")

    def ten(self):
        print("You pressed ten")

main_window = Tk()
canvas = Canvas(main_window, width=650, height=300, bg='grey')
canvas.grid()

window_one()
main_window.mainloop()  # ADDED.
```

Comment: Many thanks for your answers, i'm quite new to the language so i'm still trying to figure out how everything works, martins answer worked great and it now runs as normal so thank you martin :).

Comment: Hurd: You're welcome. While Python's relatively easy to learn, `tkinter` isn't — because it's a GUI framework, is poorly documented, and what authoritative documentation there once has gone [offline](https://web.archive.org/web/20201105231837/http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/). It's also not "pythonic" in the sense that it doesn't behave in the manner you would expect from other Python modules. In other words, you've chosen the learn the language in less than an ideal way and might get the wrong idea about how things are supposed to work — not that there's anything wrong with that. `;¬)`

Answer (score 2):

Your mistake is in the first line of the code you posted (please, fix it; it doesn't look right).

Your code includes this: `Button(main_window="ένα/1"`
The `Button` class does not have an option `main_window`, and thus an error is raised.

You did define a `main_window` instance, so did you mean to do:
`Button(main_window,text="ένα/1", font="Gothic 26",bg="red",width=3,command=self.one)` instead? This way your intended text is the text on the button too.

Comment: `text="ένα/1"`?

Comment: @TheLizzard that makes sense.